# Need to make toggle option

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

> I am using select2 plugin for custom combobox and auto complete. Now i need to make toggle like if all select disable to select other option or if i select other option need to hide/clear all option.

Main theme

1. If select all option clear other optio

```js
$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%'
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>




<select class="custom-select"  multiple="multiple">
  <option selected value="All">All</option>
  <option value="All">Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="All">Pokhara</option>
  <option value="All">Lalitpur</option>
</select>
```

n
 2. If select other option clear all option

Now i have tried through . Please have a look code and help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed that no one has answered your question. Unfortunately, this features appears to be vacant in the plugin.  But there is **always** a work around.

### Avoiding Recursion

In order to do this you need to invoke a change event to update the select2 container and while also monitoring a change event change the value for the select.  That would cause recursion; so, I added a variable called `flagAvoidRecursion`.  Basically on the first call of change on our select we set the recursion flag to `true`.  Then we ignore the following `.on("change")` invocation and reset our recursion flag.

### You need unique values

In order to get this to work, we have to set the value, meaning that every object in the select should have a unique value.

### Give it a go:

```js
flagAvoidRecursion = false;
previous = ["All"];
$("select").select2({
  tags: "true",
  placeholder: "Select an option",
  allowClear: true,
  width: '100%'
}).on('change', function () {
  if (flagAvoidRecursion) {
    flagAvoidRecursion = false;
    return;
  }
  value = $(this).val();
  flagAvoidRecursion = true;
  if (value.length === $(".custom-select option").length -1) {
   $(this).val(["All"]);
  } else if (previous.indexOf("All") === -1 && previous.indexOf("All") !== -1) {
   $(this).val(["All"])
  } else if (value.indexOf("All") != -1 && value.length > 1) {
   temp = value;
   temp.splice(temp.indexOf("All"),1)
   $(this).val(temp);
  }
  previous = value;
  $(this).trigger("change");
});
```

```css
.select2-container {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>




<select class="custom-select"  multiple="multiple">
  <option selected value="All">All</option>
  <option value="Kathmandu">Kathmandu</option>
  <option value="Pokhara">Pokhara</option>
  <option value="Lalitpur">Lalitpur</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yes its good but its working as toggle. Now i am expecting little bit different. Now its clearing after selecting any option. But it will clear other if selecting all option. But we can choose multiple place like
We can select kathmandu,pokhara together but after selecting all option other will clear

Comment: Waw... Now we are almost close to right answer. Now its working except now if we select kathmandu, lalitpur we can't select all option. I am expecting even we have select multiple option and select all option other will clear and must show all optio.

But other is working fine and its really great thanks